# PHP Push Notification for iOS works at command line, but not with Apache

Tags: php, ios, push-notification, pem, apn

Hi I am sending push notification, which works great at command line, but not when running it as a php web page.

The paths are correct apn and and passphrase (exact same code).

I run the page, but fails when being called by apache.

I get these error/warnings:

```
Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure in ..pushnotifications.php on line 31

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in ..pushnotifications.php on line 31

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in ..pushnotifications.php on line 31

Failed to connect: 0
```

Code:

```
public function iOS($data, $devicetoken, $sandbox) {
    $deviceToken = $devicetoken;

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    if($sandbox) {
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',  __DIR__.'/apn/apns-dev-cert.pem');
    } else {
        stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert',  __DIR__.'/apn/apns-prod-cert.pem');
    }
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', self::$passphrase);
    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    // 'gateway.push.apple.com:2195'; //Production
    // 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'; // Sandbox
    if($sandbox) {
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    } else {
        $fp = stream_socket_client(
            'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
            $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
    }

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
    // Create the payload body
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => array(
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'body' => $data['body'],
         ),
        'sound' => $data['sound'],
        'badge' => $data['badge']
    );
    // Encode the payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    // Build the binary notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    // Send it to the server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    // Close the connection to the server
    fclose($fp);
    if (!$result)
        return 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        return 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: can you show the code in the line 31, because it is mentioning the line 31

Comment: can you confirm the path of the .pem files,

Comment: $sandbox = true;


 $msg_payload = array (
  'title' => 'Test',
  'body' => 'You have received a new order',
  'sound' => 'default',
  'badge' => 3
 );
 
 
 $deviceToken = '994A7663BCA0D0EC75BC6923D27741CC1D2C1E089995EF0BF632185CAAFDCA35';
 
   echo PushNotifications::iOS($msg_payload, $deviceToken, $sandbox);

Comment: This is line 31: $fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

Comment: check the path of your .pem files, or check that the profile of this app is not expired

Comment: Hi Fahad, everything works at command line "php push.php", but when I use we webpage to open the page "http://website.com/push.php" it does not. The file path is correct and so it passphrase etc, since it works at command line.

Comment: i have the same problem, i solved it by providing the proper path of the .pem files

Answer (score 0):

After lots of frustration the Path was the issue. I did not want to put the pem file in the same path as code, but that was the only way it worked!

Command line worked if I put in a different path, but Apache did not, both worked if it was in the same folder as code.

Hope it helps others.

Thank you Fahad Jamal for pointing me in right direction.